# How can I optimize quanteda to work with large data sets?

Tags: r

I have the following code and was wondering if it could be optimized further.  I have more than 4gb of data. The data that I am drawing from looks like this.  Also, how do I keep the metadata that I originally included in data file? The data looks like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/72hl3kh894w5rg0/Sample.RData?dl=0

```
 require(quanteda)
 require(tm)


 #a=Doc$content[0:length(Doc$content)]
 a=Doc$content[0:1000]

 b=(lapply(a, `[[`, 1))

 #df = as.data.frame(b, col.names="text")
 df= data.frame(matrix(unlist(b), nrow=1000, byrow=T), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 colnames(df)="text"
 dfCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(df$text)) 

 token <- tokenize(dfCorpus$content[1:1000])

 x=dfm(token)

 g= textstat_simil(x, method="cosine")
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but you might want to post this on CrossValidated.